# Error when saving figure as eps in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, eps

I'm trying to save a figure in the eps format using the following code:

```
plt.savefig("test.eps", format="eps")
```

but I get the error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py", line      258, in set_linewidth
self._pswriter.write("%1.3f setlinewidth\n"%linewidth)

TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

How do I fix this? I have Matplotlib 1.3.1

Comment: have you tried it without specifying `format="eps"`?

Comment: Check: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3332

Answer (score 7):

I figured out the issue just now. It seems that when you save figures as eps, you need to make sure that all figure properties are floats. I had a command 'linewidth = 1'. It needs to be 'linewidth=1.0'. Then it works. Strange that other formats such as svg work without issues.

Thanks!

Emmanuel